# watir-webdriver result not same as manual test

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, watir, sap-enterprise-portal

... or when is a click not a click..?

I'm testing SAP Enterprise Portal using cucumber & watir-webdriver.

During manual tests I observe the portal behaving as expected.
During the cucumber tests (same user+pass) the portal behaves differently and my test fail.

To be more specific: there is a bookmark in the portal that has the correct URL during manual testing, yet during automated testing it points to "/irj/portalapps/com.sap.portal.navigation.helperservice/html/child.html". This popup is always blank...

I get this using WinXP+IE7 and Win7+IE8.

Is there any evidence of the webdriver behaving differently to a user?

---

I was trying to automate testing in SAP Enterprise Portal. The challenge with SAP EP is that the HTML is composed of multiple nested, dynamic `<iframes>` - sometimes 10+ deep! Due to this I had to abandon cucumber/watir-webdriver and I switched to HP QTP with the SAP EP plugin.

The subsequent comments I made were an attempt at sharing the gem versions - I got the formatting all wrong and they looked like some spam bot was attacking the site... I am considering deleting them, but I'm not sure if this will help.

Comment: gem list

addressable (2.3.2)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.1.3)
childprocess (0.3.5)
commonwatir (3.0.0)
cucumber (1.2.1)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
ffi (1.1.5 x86-mingw32)
firewatir (1.9.4)
gherkin (2.11.4 x86-mingw32)
hoe (3.1.0)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.4)
libwebsocket (0.1.5)
mini_magick (3.2.1)
minitest (2.5.1)
multi_json (1.3.6)
nokogiri (1.5.5 x86-mingw32)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rautomation (0.7.2)
rdoc (3.9.4)
rspec (2.11.0)
rspec-core (2.11.1)
rspec-expectations (2.11.3)
rspec-mocks (2.11.3)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
s4t-utils (1.0.4)
selenium-webdriver (2.25.0)

Comment: subexec (0.0.4)
syntax (1.0.0)
user-choices (1.1.6.1)
watir (3.0.0)
watir-classic (3.2.0)
watir-webdriver (0.6.1)
win32-api (1.4.8 x86-mingw32)
win32-process (0.7.0)
win32screenshot (1.0.7)
windows-api (0.4.2)
windows-pr (1.2.2)
xml-simple (1.1.1)
yajl-ruby (1.1.0 x86-mingw32)

Comment: There isn't the right kind of information here. I can't reproduce this problem, either mentally or actually, with what you have provided. What does the code under test look like? What does the step definition and supporting test framework code look like?